# Looking for infinite relation in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table like this:

```
Child | Parent
```

and put same data in using numbers to identify each child parent like so:

```
Child | Parent
---------------
1      2
2      1
3      4
5      4
```

The first 2 rows form a sort of infinite relation, as in 2 is the parent of 1, but 1 is also the parent of 2, so it's a never ending cycle in searching for the parent.
How would I find all rows with this sort of relation in SQL?
I was thinking I have to use

```
START WITH and CONNECT BY
```

but can't quite work out the query to run, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have written so far. (Even anything that did not work, yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does a simple inner join to the same table not do what you need?

```
SELECT table1.Parent as Row, table1.Child as OtherRow
FROM table table1
    inner join table table2
    ON table1.Parent = table2.Child
    AND table1.Child = table2.Parent
```

This would give you the "Parent->Child" row for each match, like so:

```
Row | OtherRow
----|----------
  1 |  2
```

But you could then use the result as a sub-query to pull out all the rows

eg

```
SELECT table.Parent as Parent, table.Child as Child
FROM table
    INNER JOIN (that query) query
    ON (table.Parent = query.Row AND table.Child = query.OtherRow)
        OR (table.Parent = query.OtherRow AND table.Child = query.Row)
```

This would give you

```
Parent | Child
-------|------
   1   |   2
   2   |   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use NOCYCLE option with pseudocolumn CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE.

Write your hierarchical query and it should fail because of that loop. Then add NOCYCLE option and CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE column to select clause and it will help you identify loops.

Very good example is here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_connect_by_loop.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52315